# I can just access Google and YouTube via a Wi-Fi hotspot created by my Windows 7 laptop. What’s wrong?

Tags: wi-fi, windows, wifi-hotspot, dns, wlan

I have followed every step of [this instruction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dmUDCTVYuQ), but my Android phone can only access Google and YouTube – and no other websites. What is wrong?

It may be due to a DNS-server problem, but I cannot figure out how to fix this. When connecting to the hotspot, I cannot change any DNS-settings.

Comment: This is everything I have found: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOvzH.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6fvP.png). Changing the IP-preferences to “static” and typing in the addresses of Google-DNS-Servers does not help, because I cannot click on “save”.

Comment: I have entered the configured (preferred) IP address and also used it for my gateway. But when I enter the gateway as DNS 1, my phone won’t let me save the settings. So, I have tried to use `8.8.8.8` as DNS 1 and `8.8.4.4` as DNS 2, but then, I will have no access to the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Since the hosted Wi-Fi network is just like any normal Wi-Fi connection, you have to modify it, preferably using static IP address (this lets you change DNS settings as well)

- Firstly check your IP, DNS settings on your windows machine by running `ipconfig/all`. Take note of the Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter.
- Basically you need to check its configured (Preferred) IP address, you need this later to use as your **gateway** and(or) **primary DNS server**.
- On your android device, long press on your newly created network and select modify.
- On the IP settings, select Static and choose the IP address (check with your gateway for IP address range e.g gateway= `192.168.37.1`, your desired IP will be anything from `192.168.37.1-255` etc)
- Fill the first DNS (aka DNS 1) with the gateway IP address
- Second entry choose any custom DNS e.g `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4`(Alternatively you can configure all Google DNS entries)

**Edit**

- Your issue seems strange I reckon you need to reset IP settings and flush DNS:
- open command prompt and enter the commands:

  ```
  netsh winsock reset all
  netsh int 6to4 reset all
  netsh int ipv4 reset all
  netsh int ipv6 reset all
  netsh int httpstunnel reset all
  netsh int isatap reset all
  netsh int portproxy reset all
  netsh int tcp reset all
  netsh int teredo reset all
  ```

*This will clear the stored DNS cache in Windows. When the DNS becomes corrupt you will not be able to get to some sites. Flushing and rebuilding the DNS will fix that problem.
Also resets Winsock entries & resets TCP/IP stack.*

**Update**

- The problem has since been **resolved** by using the settings below in the Internet Protocol property (of the configured adapter) in Windows:

[image]

Then on your android device set up static settings as describe above

---

This successfully resolved the matter:

> You forgot to mention that The preferred and alternative DNS server
>   should be 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 in Windows’ Internet Protocol
>   Properties. You did not write anything into it, and I did not think
>   about it either. But now it works perfectly!

Comment: No, the problem is still prevalent. And even if I enter no domain and just an IP address, I still do not have access to the internet. I have presented the problem to a friend of mine who is interested in this kind of issue, too. If he will succeed and I can successfully copy his way of solving the problem, I will post it here. If I cannot solve it, something on my computer must function in a wrong way and both of you have given me perfect advice.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61608/discussion-on-answer-by-xavier-fakerat-i-can-just-access-google-and-youtube-via).